# PayPal send payment to email

Tags: android, paypal, payment

Hi i'm developing an application and at a specific point i need to be able to send money to a user. Available resources are users paypal email and merchant info. Could you please provide me an example.So far i've tried the available examples but in all of them the user logs in and pays from his account , he pays he is not payed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending money to users should be done on the merchant's server, using [PayPal's REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/).  The REST APIs use OAuth2, so the merchant will need to sign up for credentials (client_id/secret).  Then, you can use a [server side SDK](https://github.com/paypal), or make the REST calls yourself.

Comment: How can i use Paypal's REST Api since it doesn't offer support for the mobile part? or am i wrong? I can't create a token or Authenticate like PayPal's REST examples.

Comment: I guess I did not fully grok the use case.  I was under the impression that you want to enable a merchant to pay an arbitrary user.  If that is incorrect, are you looking to build an app that allows an arbitrary PayPal user to log in and pay another arbitrary PayPal user?  This use case requires a 'facilitator', and is not possible with the current mobile SDKs.  You would have to be use the [legacy MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/).

Comment: What i need is to make an app on which a user gathers points and points turn into $. When the user wants he can withdraw a part or all of his money. How can i do that in an android application without being necessary a login from the merchant part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, in your scenario, someone must have the money to pay the user, and you'll have to authenticate with that someone, somehow, to authorize the payment.  If it's not the merchant, then it's the facilitator, and the new REST APIs do not support this use case yet.